# How to change origin of a layer in stroke in Grease Pencil?

Tags: grease-pencil, layers, origin

May I ask how to change origin of a layer in stroke?
Cuz all the layer will be affect in the object mode
while the option [origin to geometry] is not available in the edit mode

Comment: Layers don't have individual origin/pivot point, they all share the object's origin. But you can use multiple objects or parent layers to bones,

Answer (score 0):

In Edit Mode, you select the point where you want the origin to be. Then Shift+S > cursor to selected.

In Object Mode, Right Click > Cursor to Selected.